# Crystal Report : formula for Splitting string on / and concatenating it with other string

Tags: crystal-reports, substring, crystal-reports-xi

I have string coming in this format `WORVS/000017/0005`.

I want to split the string on `/`. I want only `000017` from this string and further I had another column to which it has to be concatenated.

I need a formula for same.

Answer (score 10):

Create a formula and add below code.

```
Split (dbfield,"/")[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have an eye to this solution, Its Simple, Splitting "Full Name"  into First and Last , keeping, Excluding Last name and returning First Name part.
[Splitting String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23601313/1147352)